# Pair production by collision

Tags: particle-physics

Electron Positron pairs can be created via three process:

1. Photon-Photon interaction
2. Photon-Particle interaction
3. Particle-Particle interaction

I want to know how 2. and 3. can create electron - positron pair.

Comment: Is the answer "as long as they have enough excess energy" not enough for you? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Answer (score 9):

Electron positron pairs can appear whenever there exists enough energy and electromagnetic interactions.

Photon photon to produce an e+e- is disfavored as far as crossections go because of the great number of vertices involved in the [Feynman diagram](http://oer.physics.manchester.ac.uk/NP/Notes/Notes/Notesse30.xht)

[image: two photon]

One of the outgoing photons, if it has enough energy can be a virtual photon in a diagram [creating a pair](http://www.quantumdiaries.org/tag/feynman-diagrams/) , joining a) with the two photon diagram.

[image: photon to e+e-]

The same is true for photon-particle and particle-particle particle interactions, a virtual photon with enough energy creates an e+e- pair.

[image: genericdiagram]

The outgoing photon can be virtual and given enough energy can produce e+e- pairs .

To learn about putting together Feynman diagrams have a look [here.](http://teachers.web.cern.ch/teachers/archiv/HST2002/feynman/)